# how let my app know, when Android is scanning the wlan

Tags: android, wifi, network-scan

I don't know whether it's possible: I need to register my android app (it's a backgroundservice) to let it know, when the android system is scanning for wlan-hotspots.
I don't want to do this manually in my service every 5 minutes because of battery-reasons.

Is there a way to call my service everytime the os is scanning the wlan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to register broadcast receiver for that with `ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION` action look for this article http://www.krvarma.com/2010/08/android-network-connectivity-broadcastreceiver/

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I found this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION, this works a little bit better for me :). I didn't know what i have to search for, broadcast receiver was the keyword.